# I would like to know what this circuit is

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, identification, embedded, pcb-antenna

I'm a engineer of embedded systems and I'm studying a 4G modem. The circuit has a component that I want to identify but the reference  is apparently wrong. The reference printed in the circuit is H51RFA but I couldn't find this in any place. You can see a picture below.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: What does it say on the IC itself? It's possible that it's an RF amplifier, TX/RX switch, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that (1) the indicated component is labelled H51RFA? and (2) You cannot locate a datasheet for it?

Comment: You can go a step backwards and find a datasheet of the module below, then you will find what is the role of that IC.

Comment: Could be an RF switch. Can we see the rest of the PCB to follow the other wide microstrip trace emerging from the right side of it?

Comment: below, that's a quectel module, so probably a cellular modem. This makes the RF switch to switch rapidly between transmitting and receiving likely, but seeing the stripline runs off to the right, this might also be used to switch the antenna between that modem and e.g. a Wifi or GPS chipset. "black square IC" sadly isn't very informative.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the name printed on the "black square IC" is H51RFA, but I couldn't find the datasheet anywhere.

Comment: @enhzflep exactly

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I already took a look at the quectel module and this input pin is for antennas.

Comment: @nanofarad only "H51RFA", but i couldn't find the datasheet anywhere

Comment: @alef.lieno We're not going to just trust random links on the word of people we don't know saying they're safe. Edit your question to include the image.

Comment: ok, sorry @Hearth

Comment: @MarkLeavitt i've edit the post with a better picture.

Comment: Probably it is a RF switch, between external and internal antenna.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt ty so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device is a 4g cellular modem/router, and the chip is very likely an RF switch to allow selection between the internal antenna (visible on the PCB) and an external antenna jack (visible at the lower right corner of the photo).

Being a switch external to the modem, its purpose is to support basic "diversity" reception. The modem can compare signal strength and quality between the internal and external antenna and choose the one providing the best signal.

The 4G standard also supports "MIMO" antenna configurations which are more advanced, using the two antennas simultaneously to increase data throughput. However, I believe this requires connecting both antennas directly to the modem, not switching between them externally, so I don't think your unit has true MIMO.

Identifying the chip remains "an exercise for the reader". At a major distributor (e.g. Digikey) website, you'll find the RF Switches category. Choose a manufacturer (there will be less than a dozen), look for a chip that's physically similar, pull up the datasheet, and look at the product coding. Usually the first set of digits is a short form of their product number (H51 in your case) and the second is a manufacturing lot (RFA). Good luck!

Comment: Well this doesn't really answer the question, it's _probably_ an antenna switch but there are just so many manufacturers, none of the well-known ones match. Also, this could be for antenna diversity, semi duplex or software-defined radio... it's not obvious what the purpose is either.

Comment: Also after a bit of "exercise for the reader" I'm fairly certain it is actually _not_ a RF switch (which was my first guess too). Instead it appears to be a power amp from AD. Not going to down vote, but I'm quite sure this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Lundin There was an additional picture (missing now?) that showed the feed to an external antenna jack. And why would a 4G cellular modem have a separate 19 dB gain power amplifier, spec'd to cover the 5 - 20 GHz band (not 4G frequencies) added to the antenna feedline? How would the received signal from the antenna be fed back through the power amplifier to the modem's antenna terminal?

Comment: I haven't found the exact part (it is not HMC451LC, I just picked that one as an example) and I agree that an antenna switch makes more sense - especially if that other trace leaving the picture goes to a 2nd antenna - but then everything matches these AD parts: the package, the pin-out and chip marking.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt i've add the image again

Comment: @ÁlefHuan Okay so it is 2 different antennas. The metal part at the bottom of the new pic looks like a right angle SMA (with sketchy soldering). It ought to be an antenna switch then. I'll delete my answer. Still, quite a coincidence that the same package, pinout and part marking exists on another RF component.

Comment: @Lundin sorry for not keep the image, i confused you. Ty for the answer btw